# How to use text-to-speech using ActionScript or Air?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, text-to-speech, sapi

I want to use SAPI Text-To-Speech engine from my ActionScript or Air application. is this possible ? what are the other alternatives ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Director / Shockwave can hook in to the native speech API of the OS. For Flash you can generate the speech on the server and download it as a an mp3.

Comment: Thanks for replay,
Director / Shockwave has Speech Xtra which uses SAPI engine for Text-to-Speech. But I want to achieve this using ActionScript or Air runtime only..

Answer (score 1):

I think you should play with [Alchemy](http://labs.adobe.com/wiki/index.php/Alchemy:Documentation:Developing_with_Alchemy:C_API).